# Cassandra settings tuning for CAS updates

Tags: cassandra

1. What are the settings to consider for lightweight transactions( Compare and Set) in Cassandra–2.1.8?

   a.    We are using token aware load balancing policy with a LeveledCompactionStrategy setting on the table. Table has skinny rows with a single column in the primary key. We use prepared statements for all the queries and are prepared once and cached. 
   b.    The below are the settings,
     i.    Max Heap – 4G, New Heap – 1G, 4 Core CPU, CentOS
    ii.    Connection pool is based on the concurrency settings for the test.

   ```
   final PoolingOptions pools = new PoolingOptions();
   pools.setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, concurrency);
   pools.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, maxConnections);
   pools.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, maxConnections);
   pools.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, maxConnections);
   pools.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, maxConnections);
   ```

   iii.    protocol version – V3
   iv. Set tcp delay to true to disable Nagle’s algorithm. (default)
   v.  Compression is enabled.

2. Throughput increases with concurrency on a single connection. For CAS RW, the throughput does scale at same rate as Simple RW.

```
100000 requests, 1 thread    Simple RW CAS RW
Mean rate (ops/sec)          643        265.4
Mean latency (ms)            1.554      3.765
Median latency (ms)          1.332      2.996
75th percentile latency (ms) 1.515      3.809
95th percentile latency (ms) 2.458      8.121
99th percentile latency (ms) 5.038     11.52
Standard latency deviation   0.992      2.139

100000 requests, 25 threads   Simple RW CAS RW
Mean rate (ops/sec)           7686       1881
Mean latency (ms)             3.25      13.29
Median latency (ms)           2.695     12.203
75th percentile latency (ms)  3.669     14.389
95th percentile latency (ms)  6.378     20.139
99th percentile latency (ms) 11.59      61.973
Standard latency deviation    3.065      6.492
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important consideration for speed on LWT is partition contention. If you have several updates on a single partition, it will be slower. Beyond that, you are looking at machine performance tuning.

There is a free, full course here to help with that: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds210-operations-and-performance-tuning